# ASP.NET Core, get notification when a user signs in

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, razor-pages

I use ASP.NET Core Razor pages with its authentication provider (individual account).
I need to run some code when a user logs in.
Where can I put this code, is there any callback that is being called when a login happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this. You can create custom login page with custom model (see more [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/identity/customising-identity)). Or if you want to use the default one - you can create custom `SignInManager` and override the method used to signin the user by the login default page (`Identity/Account/Login`) for simple auth:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
    {
       // ...
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager<MySignMan<IdentityUser>>(); // use your custom signin manager

class MySignMan<T> : SignInManager<T> where T : class
{
    public MySignMan(UserManager<T> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<T> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, ILogger<SignInManager<T>> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes, IUserConfirmation<T> confirmation) : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes, confirmation)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(T user, string password, bool isPersistent, bool lockoutOnFailure)
    {
        var signInResult = await base.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, isPersistent, lockoutOnFailure);
        if (signInResult.Succeeded)
        {
            // do something here
        }
        return signInResult;
    }
}
```

P.S.

Note that this is implementation depended and in future versions you may need to either override another method or use completely other workaround.

Comment: Thanks, it works.
How is it possible to access ApplicationDbContext from PasswordSignInAsync?

Comment: @user3136169 add another parameter to `MySignMan` ctor and store it in private field.